# Add action to wp_head from a callback render gutenberg function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, wordpress-hook, wordpress-action

I developed a custom slider block, and i'd like to add an action to the wp_head in the callback render function.

Obviously it's not working using `add_action('wp_head', .... )` because the render callback function is called after the wp_head hook is parsed and rendered.
Well... that's what i'm thinking.

How can i add something in the head dinamically, like a `<link rel="preload" src="..." />` if there is a video in some field, from the callback render function of a gutenberg block?

Comment: Hello @vitta , have you found a solution for this? I have the same question

Comment: Nope, sorry… I managed to do it manually in the functions.php file